# EmbeddedKafka AdminClient shuts down before Spring app starts for tests

Tags: spring-boot, spring-test, spring-kafka, spring-boot-test

I'm trying to write integration tests for a Spring Kafka app (Spring Boot 2.0.6, Spring Kafka 2.1.10) and am seeing lots of instance of `INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor - Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x166e432ebec0001 type:create cxid:0x5e zxid:0x24 txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/brokers/topics/my-topic/partitions Error:KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /brokers/topics/my-topic/partitions` and various flavors of the path (`/brokers`, `/brokers/topics`, etc.) that show in the logs before the Spring app starts. The AdminClient then shuts down and this message is logged:

```
DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector - [SocketServer brokerId=0] Connection with /127.0.0.1 disconnected
java.io.EOFException: null
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFromReadableChannel(NetworkReceive.java:124)
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFrom(NetworkReceive.java:93)
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.receive(KafkaChannel.java:235)
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.read(KafkaChannel.java:196)
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.attemptRead(Selector.java:547)
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:483)
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:412)
at kafka.network.Processor.poll(SocketServer.scala:575)
at kafka.network.Processor.run(SocketServer.scala:492)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I'm using the @ClassRule startup option in the test like so:

```
@ClassRule
@Shared
private KafkaEmbedded embeddedKafka = new KafkaEmbedded(1, true, 'my-topic')
```

, autowiring a `KafkaTemplate`, and setting the Spring properties for the connection based on the embedded Kafka values:

```
def setupSpec() {
    System.setProperty('spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers', embeddedKafka.getBrokersAsString());
    System.setProperty('spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.zkNodes', embeddedKafka.getZookeeperConnectionString());
}
```

Once the Spring app starts, I can see again instance of the user-level KeeperException messages: `o.a.z.server.PrepRequestProcessor        : Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x166e445836d0001 type:setData cxid:0x6b zxid:0x2b txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/config/topics/__consumer_offsets Error:KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /config/topics/__consumer_offsets`.

Any idea where I'm going wrong here? I can provide other setup information and log messages but just took an educated guess on what may be most helpful initially.

Comment: Maybe you just can share with us a simple GitHub project to play and reproduce? Thanks

Comment: @ArtemBilan here's a sample project, thanks for taking a look: https://github.com/nateha1984/kafka-int-test-sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Spock, but what I know that `@KafkaListener` method is invoked on its own thread, therefore you can't just assert it in the `then:` block directly.

You need to ensure somehow a blocking wait in your test-case.

I tried with the `BlockingVariable` against the real service not mock and I see in logs your `println(message)`. But that `BlockingVariable` still doesn't work for me somehow:

```
@DirtiesContext
@SpringBootTest(classes = [KafkaIntTestApplication.class])
@ActiveProfiles('test')
class CustomListenerSpec  extends Specification {

    @ClassRule
    @Shared
    public KafkaEmbedded embeddedKafka = new KafkaEmbedded(1, false, 'my-topic')

    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<String, String> template

    @SpyBean
    private SimpleService service

    final def TOPIC_NAME = 'my-topic'

    def setupSpec() {
        System.setProperty('spring.kafka.bootstrapServers', embeddedKafka.getBrokersAsString());
    }

    def 'Sample test'() {
        given:
        def testMessagePayload = "Test message"
        def message = MessageBuilder.withPayload(testMessagePayload).setHeader(KafkaHeaders.TOPIC, TOPIC_NAME).build()
        def result = new BlockingVariable<Boolean>(5)
        service.handleMessage(_) >> {
            result.set(true)
        }

        when: 'We put a message on the topic'
        template.send(message)

        then: 'the service should be called'
        result.get()
    }
}
```

And logs are like this:

```
2018-11-05 13:38:51.089  INFO 8888 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : partitions assigned: [my-topic-0, my-topic-1]
Test message

BlockingVariable.get() timed out after 5,00 seconds

    at spock.util.concurrent.BlockingVariable.get(BlockingVariable.java:113)
    at com.example.CustomListenerSpec.Sample test(CustomListenerSpec.groovy:54)

2018-11-05 13:38:55.917  INFO 8888 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@11ebb1b6: startup date [Mon Nov 05 13:38:49 EST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
```

Also I had to add this dependency:

```
testImplementation "org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core"
```

**UPDATE**

OK. There real problem that `MockConfig` was not visible for the test context configuration and that `@Import(MockConfig.class)` does the trick. Where `@Primary` also gives us additional signal what bean to pick up for the injection in the test class.

Answer (score 0):

@ArtemBilan's response set me on the right path so thanks to him for chiming in, and I was able to figure it out after looking into other `BlockingVariable` articles and examples. I used `BlockingVariable` in a mock's response instead of as a callback. When the mock's response is invoked, make it set the value to true, and the `then` block just does `result.get()` and the test passes.

```
@DirtiesContext
@ActiveProfiles('test')
@SpringBootTest
@Import(MockConfig.class)
class CustomListenerSpec extends TestSpecBase {

    @ClassRule
    @Shared
    private KafkaEmbedded embeddedKafka = new KafkaEmbedded(1, false, TOPIC_NAME)

    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<String, String> template

    @Autowired
    private SimpleService service

    final def TOPIC_NAME = 'my-topic'

    def setupSpec() {
        System.setProperty('spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers', embeddedKafka.getBrokersAsString());
    }

    def 'Sample test'() {
        def testMessagePayload = "Test message"
        def message = MessageBuilder.withPayload(testMessagePayload).setHeader(KafkaHeaders.TOPIC, TOPIC_NAME).build()
        def result = new BlockingVariable<Boolean>(5)
        service.handleMessage(_ as String) >> {
            result.set(true)
        }

        when: 'We put a message on the topic'
        template.send(message)

        then: 'the service should be called'
        result.get()
    }
}
```